# Traducir descripciones de ES a EN con DeepL con VBA

Tags: api, vba, web-scrapping, deepl

He tratado de utilizar varios codigos disponibles en la red para lograr traducir descripciones de español a ingles, sin ningun buen resultado, tengo algunas opciones (macros) que comparto a continuacion:

Primera opcion (Op 1): codigo VBA donde se utiliza la API-FREE de la pagina DeepL

```
Option Explicit
Function deepl(lang As String, Text As String) As String
    Dim api_key As String
    api_key = "Input_your_DeepL_APIKEY(FREE)"
    Dim URL As String
    URL = "https://api-free.deepl.com/v2/translate"
    Dim paramStr As String
    paramStr = "auth_key=" + api_key + "&target_lang=" + lang + "&text=" + Text
    Dim r As Object
    Set r = CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
    r.Open "POST", URL, False
    r.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; utf-8"
    r.send (paramStr)
    Dim json As Object
    Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(r.responseText)
    deepl = json("translations")(1)("text")
End Function
```

Segunda opcion (Op 2): codigo VBA donde se utiliza el complemento selenium y busqueda en DeepL por Google Chrome

```
Public Function traductordeepl(txt As String, inputLang As String, outputLang As String)
Dim URL As String
Dim driver As New WebDriver

URL = "https://www.deepl.com/translator#" & inputLang & "/" & outputLang & "/" & txt
driver.Start "Chrome"
driver.Timeouts.ImplicitWait = 5000
driver.Get URL

traductordeepl = driver.FindElementByCss("textarea.lmt__textarea.lmt__target_textarea.lmt__textarea_base_style").Attribute("value")
driver.Close

End Function
```

Tercera opcion (Op 3): codigo VBA donde se utiliza la api-free de deepl en el resultado con un boton

```
Const AUTH_KEY As String = "es"

Private Function deepL_translate(ByVal srcText As String) As String
    Dim httpReq As XMLHTTP60
    Set httpReq = New XMLHTTP60

    Call httpReq.Open("POST", _
                      "https://api-free.deepl.com/v2/translate?auth_key=" & AUTH_KEY & _
                      "&text=" & srcText & "&target_lang=en")

    Call httpReq.send

    Do While httpReq.readyState < 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    deepL_translate = httpReq.responseText

    Set httpReq = Nothing

End Function

Private Function getResultText(ByVal resText As String) As String
    Dim pos As Long
    Dim res As String

    pos = InStr(resText, "text")

    If pos > 0 Then
        res = Mid(resText, pos + Len("text") + 3)
        res = Left(res, Len(res) - 4)
    Else
        res = ""
    End If

    getResultText = res

End Function

Public Sub Traduccion()
    Dim srcText As String
    Dim res As String

    srcText = Range("B3").Value
    srcText = WorksheetFunction.EncodeURL(srcText)    '

    res = deepL_translate(srcText)

    Range("D3").Value = getResultText(res)

End Sub
```

Agradezco su ayuda en este tema ya que me sale error en el resultado deseado, agragando que he activado las referencias y complementos necesarios y correspondientes para lograr la ejecucion correcta de esos codigos ya mencionados anteriormente.

***Informacion actualizada:***

Los errores que obtengo en las 3 opciones los muestro a continuacion:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde la Op 1 y 2 me da como resultado #¡VALOR! y la Op 3 no me arroja ningun resultado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo estas referencias activadas en vba

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal o que me falta?

Lo que quiero es traducir una lista de descipciones dispuesta en la columna A atravez de VBA en la columana B,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

he intentado ver si funciona con las referencias que muestro, y paso por paso pero el error es en el resultado.

***Actualizacion: Traductor Google con VBA***

Este codigo vba (macro) funciana bien con el traductor de `https://translate.google.com/?hl=es`, hay alguna forma de hacerlo con el traductor `https://www.deepl.com`?

```
Public Function GoogleTranslate(strInput As String, strFromSourceLanguage As String, strToTargetLanguage As String) As String
    Dim strURL As String
    Dim objHTTP As Object
    Dim objHTML As Object
    Dim objDivs As Object, objDiv As Object
    Dim strTranslated As String

    strURL = "https://translate.google.com/m?hl=" & strFromSourceLanguage & _
        "&sl=" & strFromSourceLanguage & _
        "&tl=" & strToTargetLanguage & _
        "&ie=UTF-8&prev=_m&q=" & strInput

    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP") 'late binding
    objHTTP.Open "GET", strURL, False

    objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
    objHTTP.send ""

    Dim httpresponse() As Byte
    httpresponse = objHTTP.responseBody

    Set objHTML = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    With objHTML
        .Open
        .Write objHTTP.responseText
        
        .Close
    End With
    
    Set objDivs = objHTML.getElementsByTagName("div")
    
    For Each objDiv In objDivs
        
        GoogleTranslate = GoogleTranslateRecursion(objDiv.ChildNodes)

        If GoogleTranslate <> "" Then
            Exit For
        End If
        If objDiv.className = "result-container" Then
            strTranslated = objDiv.innerText
            GoogleTranslate = strTranslated
            Exit For
        End If
        
    Next objDiv


    Set objHTML = Nothing
    Set objHTTP = Nothing

End Function
```

```
Function GoogleTranslateRecursion(pobjDivs As Object) As String
    Dim objDivs As Object, objDiv As Object
    Dim strTranslated As String
    GoogleTranslateRecursion = ""
    Set objDivs = pobjDivs
    For Each objDiv In objDivs
        If objDiv.nodeName = "DIV" Then

            strTranslated = GoogleTranslateRecursion(objDiv.ChildNodes)
            
            If strTranslated <> "" Then
                GoogleTranslateRecursion = strTranslated
                Exit For
            End If
            
            If objDiv.className = "result-container" Then
                strTranslated = objDiv.innerText
                GoogleTranslateRecursion = strTranslated
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
        
    Next objDiv
End Function
```

He intentado cambiar el enlace del codigo `strURL =` por `https://www.deepl.com/translator#es/en/` pero sin buenos resultados, agradezco la ayuda que me puedan prestar en esta publicación.

***Actualizacion Opcion 2: Traductor con DeepL - VBA***

```
Public Function traductordeepl(txt As String, inputLang As String, outputLang As String)

Dim URL As String
Dim driver As New WebDriver

URL = "https://www.deepl.com/translator#" & inputLang & "/" & outputLang & "/" & txt
driver.Start "Chrome"
driver.Get URL
driver.Wait "1000"

traductordeepl = driver.FindElementByCss("textarea.lmt__textarea.lmt__target_textarea.lmt__textarea_base_style", timeout:=1000).Attribute("value")
driver.Close

End Function
```

El codigo actualizado de la Opcion 2 parece mejorar en su resultado con las modificaciones que le hice, el problema es que no traduce toda la descripcion solicitada (Columna A) como muestro en la siguiente imagen, y no descubro como superar esta particularidad, agradezco su ayuda de antemano.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La pregunta es demasiado amplia. Mucho código pero no se concreta nada. Te sugiero, por ejemplo, especificar qué errores obtienes y qué has intentado para solucionarlo. En qué parte exacta falla todo, cuándo se produce el error, si lo has debugeado step by step, etc.

Comment: Si entiendo tu actualización bien, tienes un código que te funciona correctamente con el traductor de Google, y ¿quieres hacer lo mismo con el traductor de DeepL? Si es así, por favor pon claramente `DeepL` en el titulo de tu cuestión (lástima que no valga como etiqueta) y quita los demás etiquetas (sobre todo excel, json y macros que no tienen que ver con la pregunta). No se puede ayudarte sin conocimientos de DeepL.

Comment: @AntoineL gracias por tu interes y sugerencia, ya actualice el post segun me indicas, y si correcto estas entendiendo bien la actualizacion de la publicación.

Comment: En vez de simplemente tirarle una URL al código que ya funciona, tienes que ir a la [documentación](https://www.deepl.com/docs-api) de DeepL y leer lo que te piden. No te van a recibir la petición así nada más. La documentación de la API dice que debes registrarte para que te den una clave (un authKey) que debes usar en todas las peticiones. De paso, dice que _you can translate up to 500,000 characters per month for free_, así que de gratis sólo te traduce hasta esa cantidad al mes.

Comment: Gracias @Alfabravo por el interes en el post; para obtener el AuthKey debo introducir una TC, con la Opción 2 que comparto en la publicación hay alguna forma de capturar la traduccion sin esa validacion? Ya que en esta Op 2 si cambio target por source me devuelve el origen del texto que estoy traduciendo, pero con target que es el resultado no tengo ninguna informacion devuelta, me refiero a esta linea ```deepl = driver.FindElementByCss("textarea.lmt__textarea.lmt__target_textarea.lmt__textarea_base_style").Attribute("value")```

Comment: Existe la posibilidad. Pero, como vas a usar eso en contra de los términos de uso, es posible que termines en una lista de bloqueo. Habría que jugar a hacer scrapping de la página

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Seguire intentando como hacerlo funcionar, y averiguar un poco sobre lo que mencionas de scrapping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Les comparto una solucion funcional atravez de python

```
import xlwings as xw
from pathlib import Path
import os.path as path
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

in_file = str(Path(__file__).parent / Path("Update.xlsx"))
wb = xw.Book(in_file)
wb.activate()
sht = wb.sheets['Update'].activate()
sht = wb.sheets['Update']

Urow = sht.range('A2').end('down').last_cell.row
for i in range(2, int(Urow+1)):

 txt = sht.range(f'A{i}').value

 driver = webdriver.Chrome()
 driver.get('https://www.deepl.com/translator#es/en/' + txt)
 while True:
   element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'textarea.lmt__textarea.lmt__target_textarea.lmt__textarea_base_style')))
   if(element.get_attribute('value') != ''):
     time.sleep(1)
     text_target = element.get_attribute('value')
     break

 sht.range(f'B{i}').value = text_target
 driver.quit()
```

Tal vez lo pueda lograr en VBA, si lo hago lo compartire por aca.